# Cannot compile dlib to run in Ubuntu as fast as in Windows

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, dlib

My problem is that dlib is running very slow on Ubuntu. I've always used it in Windows, and it works just great. Now I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04, and the speed is many times slower. I've used the dlib's issue template from Github, but I didn't upload it there because I'm sure is a mistake I'm making, not a dlib's bug or something like that.

### Expected Behavior and Current Behavior

I'm using dnn and svm modules of dlib. The speed when I use them on Windows is many times faster than when I use them in Ubuntu. I know it must be something wrong I'm doing, but I can't find what. The trained files come from Windows, I'm just using them to predict on Ubuntu.

### Steps to Reproduce

- Open cmake gui version 3.11.1.
- Specify CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles (the codeblocks version is 16.01)
- Check USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS
- Check DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT
- Configure and Generate

That's all I do to configure the project. Also, I have installed in my computer Intel Performance Libraries, so mkl and openmp are being used. No CUDA (but this is the same as in Windows).  The version of these libraries is 2018.2

I've also checked the flags being used when compiling, and they seem ok. Here's one as an example:

```
Building CXX object dlib/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_jpeg.cpp.o
cd /home/fgalan/dep/dlib-19.10/build/dlib && /usr/bin/c++  -DDLIB_JPEG_STATIC -I/opt/intel/mkl/include  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -DDLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT -DDLIB_DISABLE_ASSERTS -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT -DDLIB_USE_BLAS -DDLIB_USE_LAPACK -DDLIB_PNG_SUPPORT -DDLIB_USE_MKL_FFT -DLAPACK_FORCE_UNDERSCORE -DDLIB__CMAKE_GENERATED_A_CONFIG_H_FILE -DDLIB_CHECK_FOR_VERSION_MISMATCH=DLIB_VERSION_MISMATCH_CHECK__EXPECTED_VERSION_19_10_0 -mavx -Wreturn-type -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_jpeg.cpp.o -c /home/fgalan/dep/dlib-19.10/dlib/image_saver/save_jpeg.cpp
```

- **Version**: 19.10
- **Where did you get dlib**: I've cloned it, and then checkout to v19.10 tag.
- **Platform**: 
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
  Release:    16.04
  Codename:   xenial
- **Compiler**: gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609

Any idea of what could be happening, it's welcome. If more information is required, I can update the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you use gcc when compiling in Windows too?

Comment: No, on Windows I use vc14.

Comment: I've just tried with clang, and it's the same.  

clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'll try to think about what's causing it then.

Comment: Did you crosscheck in the cmake that it is really compiling using mkl?

Comment: My bad. The problem was in the preprocessing, just a step before. It was so wear that I didn't think about it. Thanks for your time @MrK.

Comment: No problem at all. Happy to hear you figured it out!